# Breeze Predicate on on to zero/or Related Porperty

Tags: breeze, predicate, one-to-one

How to filter an entity to only get records where the related property (one to zero/one relationship) is not null?
From the docs, i get this to filter cutomers with no orders:

```
var p = Predicate.create("orders", "any", "id", "!=", null).not();
var query = EntityQuery.from("Customers").where(p);
```

where customer and orders have a one to zero or many relationship.  How can i perform the same operation if customer and order had a one to zero/one relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While [addressing the count of a collection is supported by OData 4](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc406398087), breeze does not yet support OData 4, so you cannot do this with a predicate.

I see a couple alternatives:

1. Include a property on the entity from the server that tells you whether the customer has zero or one order, then create a predicate from that.
2. Filter the data on the client-side after retrieving it from the server.